# Why are there no web based API clients?

Tags: api, rest, soap

I'm currently looking to build projects for my portfolio, and it came to my mind that there are no web based API clients. Is there a reason for that? What would be the disadvantage in having them as a web application instead of a desktop application like Postman or Insomnia?

Comment: There may be browser extensions that offer that. As to why no proper website exists for that: because it cannot do anything close to what a desktop app can. Think about CORS, XSRF, Certificates, etc. All those things are controlled / handled by the browser. Postman can talk to any API. your-api-client.com can talk to basically no API because the browser will not allow it because most APIs will tell your browser to not allow requests from arbitrary domains.

Comment: REST is for M2M communication mostly not H2M.